# Change Woocommerce Checkout URL based on condition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get

I am trying to change the woocommerce checkout url based on a condition being met. The end goal is simply to append some `GET` parameters. Unfortunately, it is accomplishing nothing at the moment... nothing happens. Any ideas?

(PS. the condition is just `is_user_logged_in()` at the moment for trial sake)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 30 );
function custom_checkout_url( $checkout_url ) {

    $custom_url = site_url( '/checkout/', '?noaddress=true');


    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $custom_url;
    }
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below function to meet your requirement. By using the [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) function of WordPress, you can easily add a parameter to the url in the WordPress way. You can modify the snippet.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 30 );
function custom_checkout_url( $checkout_url ) {

    $custom_url = add_query_arg( 
        array(
        'noaddress' => 'true',
        ), $checkout_url 
    );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $custom_url;
    }

    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did it. I will also note that as I was checking for whether or not an address was set, the filter order was changed to 100 - example ``add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 100 );``

Comment: Happy to help you :)